# Razor Page Routing in the same way as in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing, razor-pages

I create a web application with Razor Pages.
I have 2 Models with one to many relationship: one `List` can hold many `Records`.

```
  public class List
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Title should be in range between 3 and 25")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]

    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

 public class Record
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Word should be in range between 3 and 25")]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]

    public string Word { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Translation should be in range between 3 and 30")]
    public string Translation { get; set; }

    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public List List { get; set; }
}
```

I need to provide navigation from `List` item to List of `Record` in the similar way as it is possible in Web API or in MVC. In Microsoft documentation I found the page about [attributes in Web Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), that behaviour that I need:

```
[Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

I need something like this:

```
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("Lists/{listId}/Records")]
    public async Task GetRecordsByList(int listId)
    {

        var allRecords = await _context.Record.ToListAsync();

        Record = allRecords.Where(w => w.ListId == listId).ToList() ;

    }
```

I am sure that is possible to provide navigation from parent model `List` to a child items List of `Record`.

UI will be like this:
From Lists 
[image]

Navigate to Records:
[image]

Desired URL should be like this:

[image]

I am sure somebody faced the same issue and fixed that!
I will be very grateful for any help or advise.

Comment: Could you show your RouteConfig? you have to register Attribute routing on your startup as well:
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

Comment: Here is a good example of implementation attribute-based routing in mvc https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: It is not MVC - it is Razor Pages. Maybe it is possible to use Controllers in Razor Page architecture, but is wrong approach. I'm sure there is an option to implement the same in Razor Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor Pages uses attribute routing by default. Routes are generated from the file paths of individual pages. You can specify parameters for routes, but you do this for a specific page by adding a route template to the `@page` directive.

The first page that you show can either be a page named *Lists.cshtml* or a page named *Index.cshtml* in a *Lists* folder. Either way, it will be available at `domain.com/lists` using the default routing. The second page can be a page named *Details.cshtml* with an override route template of `"/Lists/{listid}/Records"`:

`@page "/Lists/{listid}/Records"`

Or you can use the `AddPageRoute` method in Startup to add another route by which the Index page can be reached:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Lists/Index", "Lists/{listid}/Records");
});
```

Although that would require code in Index to determine whether it should be showing all lists or details of a selected list.

Personally, I recommend the first approach. In Razor Pages, you should aim to keep each page down to one responsibility.

See more about Razor Pages routing here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That was not an exact solution, but you gave me the right direction, and I have almost done that. I will publish it after it will fully work and satisfy all needs.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution based on answer of [Mike Brind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134725/mike-brind) looks like this:

1. I moved Records folder into Lists:
   [image]
2. The Link that navigates to Records from the Parent Link is defined in that way:

   Details

[image]

3. URL for page Lists/Records/Index was redefined to:

   @page "/Lists/{id}/Records"
4. Signature for method `OnGetAsync` was changed: int? id is now nullable.

   public async Task OnGetAsync(int? id)
       {
          ...
       }

Now URL looks like exactly like I need:

[image]

I hope it will help to somebody.